# click event is not captured on android but works on other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

```
$('#btnSearchMobile').trigger('click');

document.getElementById('btnSearchMobile').click();
```

I have tried the above 2 ways to initiate the click on the element id btnSearchMobile. It works for chrome, firefox, safari, but not on android. Do you guys have any idea why?

Sorry if it isn't clear. Do comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Try touchend, instead of click event for mobile devices.

Comment: ^ what he said.  reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent

Comment: hi, is this applicable? because all i want is to initiate a click on the element when a function is called.

Comment: Yes it is. As you effectively can only click on elements on a desktop and touch on a mobile device. Even though some touch devices can trigger the click event, but not all, so you should assign the click and touchend events.